# library test: how to create a Context?

Tags: android, junit4, android-context, android-library, android-testing

Android library test: how to create a Context? e.g.

```
src/main/java
src/androidTest/java
```

The android lib (main source set) uses android sqlite database, but does not have any Activities. The SQLiteOpenHelper needs a Context to create.

```
class MySQLiteOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    MySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context, String database, int version) {
        super(context, database, null, version);
    }
}
```

How to create a Context for testing?  How to pass the Context to junit tests under androidTest ?  e.g.

```
@Runner(Parameterized.class)
public class FooTest {
    @Test
    public void testFoo() {
        // how to get a Context instance?
        MySQLiteOpenHelper helper = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(context, "test.db", 1);
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to create a Context for testing?

Call `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` to get a `Context` for the app or module being tested.